# Will a second Ubuntu version overwrite GRUB?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, 16.04, windows, 15.10

On my drive there are 2 operating systems (2 of which are usable):
- Ubuntu 15.10 (now **EOL**)
- Windows 10 (pre-Ubuntu, now broken to all extent)

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a separate swap and ext4 partition.

My question is, **will 16.04 overwrite the current install of GRUB?**

Comment: Yes, it will, unless you tell it not to.

Comment: @mikewhatever will it keep the entries for all the other operating systems?

Comment: Consider upgrading 15.10 to 16.04 instead, unless you have a compelling reason not to.